# Help installing Ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkpad L420

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

I am on a Lenovo Thinkpad L420.  I can load the first purple screen but then it goes black with a flashing white cursor.  I have tried pressing the down key to try to run live but it doesn't work either.  After I try the live option it will go back to the black screen.  I have tried Ubuntu 14.04 lts and 16.04 as well as Linux Mint 18.  I have also tried a live dvd but it didn't work either.  This is driving me crazy.  I need this to work.  I was under the impression that Thinkpads work great with Ubuntu and such.

Comment: When the menu first comes up after boot, press F6. Try one of them and see if it allows the `Try Ubuntu` option to work. If it doesn't, reboot and try the next. Do any options work?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out finally.  There was a bug in the bios and I had to update my bios.  Now it works like a dream.  Just go to the Lenovo site then download the bios iso and burn it to a disk or put the iso on a thumb drive with poweriso.  Set the boot to optical drive first then follow the prompts.  It should install fine after that.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/downloads/migr-77079